# Align text with title tag (h2) in HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I have this code :

```
<div class="row margin-bt-5">
   <div class="col-xs-4 ft-bold">Name  &nbsp;:</div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Content</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

But because I have different font size, they are not aligned vertically. I get this :

[image]

How can I align the middle of "Name" with the middle of "Content" ? Thanks

Comment: ... and you want to achieve... what?

Comment: `vertical-align` - google

Comment: It did not work

Comment: heading tags have margin by default. Try putting `margin: 0` for `h2`.

Comment: Did you try line height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` for row.

```css
.margin-bt-5 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.margin-bt-5 h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row margin-bt-5">
   <div class="col-xs-4 ft-bold">Name  &nbsp;:</div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Content</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is not exactly what I was looking for, because Content is still below Name, but it is good enough in my case. Thanks

Comment: @bobier2  Plz try it now. I didn't see Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

```css
.margin-bt-5 h2{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row margin-bt-5">
   <div class="col-xs-4 ft-bold">Name  &nbsp;:</div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Content</h2>
   </div>
</div
```